# SQL - Iterating through ids and limit the result for each id

Tags: sql, loops, iteration

In my database, I'm keeping track of all UI events for each user in the game. And I would like to extract last 5 events for each user.

```
SELECT usr.id, evt.name, evt.utc_timestamp AS Date
FROM usr
JOIN evt ON usr.id = evt.user_id
ORDER BY Date DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This query of course will not work, because it only retrieves most recent 5 events for any user.

But what my aim is having a list which includes 5 rows for each user. Hence, is there a way to iterate through my user table and append 5 most recent events for each users ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: what RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have window functions in your database, you can do it like this:

```
select
    id, name, Date
from (
    select
        usr.id, evt.name, evt.utc_timestamp as Date,
        row_number() over(partition by usr.id ordr by evt.utc_timestamp desc) as rn
    from usr
        inner join evt on usr.id = evt.user_id
) as A
where rn <= 5
```

In SQL Server it's possible to do with apply:

```
select
    usr.id, evt.name, evt.utc_timestamp as Date
from usr
    outer apply (
        select top 5 *
        from evt
        where usr.id = evt.user_id
        order by evt.utc_timestamp desc
    ) as evt
```